# Multigraphs and Social Network Analysis

Tags: graph-theory

I am interested about Social Network Analysis (SNA) with multiple links between pairs of nodes. I'm not aware of works in this area, and I am trying to find any reference in these regards.

In particular, is there also something about SNA with negative edges, possibly multigraphs?

Comment: My guess is that multigraphs are interpreted as edge-weighted networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideas of Formal Concept Analysis may be of use to you.

There is at least one paper on the general area
"Understanding social networks using Formal Concept Analysis" 
Vaclav Snasel, Zdenek Horak and  Ajith Abraham

http://www.softcomputing.net/wi08.pdf

Answer (score 1):

To comment a bit on D.S. Stones' comment: I think that negative edges are very natural if you think of your graphs as oriented. In fact, this kind of objects are the very fundament of so-called cognitive maps, which have been around for quite a while now - although I cannot really judge how popular they still are, nowadays.
http://sipi.usc.edu/~kosko/FCM.pdf